# Detecting onContextMenu clicks in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, contextmenu

So I've successfully connected a context menu pop up to a list view in a fragment. The items show up, but when I click on them, `onContextMenuItemSelectedMenu()` is ignored and instead `onMenuItemClick()` is called in the parent activity. How can I make it so when I click the context menu items `onContextMenuItemSelectedMenu()` is called in the fragment instead. Thanks.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add("item1");
    menu.add("item2");
    menu.add("item3");      
}



@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected (android.view.MenuItem item){
    Log.i("cTest", "clicked context menu");
            return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's turned out to be the same as buttons. Both in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add("item0").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        menu.add("item1").setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
    if(itemName.equals("item0))
    {


    }
    else if (itemName.equals("item1"))
     {
     }

}
```